# Log file not UTF-8

Tags: python, logging, utf-8

I am unable to get a log file in Python due to an error when attempting to open the file: The document was not UTF-8 valid.

I have tried the following:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/Desktop/logEL.log', filemode='w', format=u'%(asctime)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG, encoding='utf-8')
```

as well as:

```
import logging

root_logger= logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # or whatever
handler = logging.FileHandler('/home/pi/Desktop/logEL.log', 'a', 'utf-8')
formatter = logging.Formatter(u'%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter) 
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Opening the log file:

[image: utf-8 not file]

Comment: What error do you get during which operation?

Comment: you should add `encoding='utf-8' to `logging.basicConfig`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no error during operation, just when opening the file

Comment: "opening the file" sounds like an operation to me. Please [edit] your question to include the traceback.

Comment: Did you delete the old log file? You are appending (`'a'` flag), so you may get a file with several different encodings.

Comment: What version of Python was the log file written with?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi always starting with a new file when testing

Comment: @VinaySajip python 2.7

Comment: Python2.7 is obsolete (and unsupported since much time). It will be difficult to find someone which remember all quirks of handling Unicode with Python 2.7 (and there were a lot of quirks). So, I think the question is valid, but it will be difficult to find someone which could answer (and possibly also install such version). BTW you should try to open the file with a better editor (and maybe one which show you the invalid characters).

Answer (score 1):

Opening the log file with nano instead of the GUI seems to be the trick.